# Clean git graph even though non-fast-forward merging

Tags: git

I'm using feature/develop/test/production branches, where merges happen from left to right.
For all branch merging I'm using non-fast-forward merge. Reason: I'd like to know when new features were added to the specific branch.

##### Problem:

The merge graph can become quite unreadable (see below). 
[image]

To make the graph more readable I'd like to keep it as straight as possible.

##### Though-of Solutions:

1. My idea was be to use fast-forward merging for develop->test and test->production. However, that way git does not seem to provide information on when the specific merge happened. Which is bad from a documentation perspective.
2. I also thought of fast-forward merging with a label for every merge. But I'm not sure if this is what labels are made for.

##### Question

Is there a way to keep merge-logs while not letting the git graph become unreadable/complex? ( *edit*: I'm using `gitk`, btw. )

Comment: Besides attempting to control the graph (to keep it simple to draw), you could attempt to control the graph-drawing software (to convince it to draw simply). To get started on that—it's a big topic!—see [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452).

Comment: This question is better suited to [programmers.se] than Stack Overflow. We disallow questions that are open to opinion (and for the most part things that are more workflow-focused than technical), whereas "best practice" &c are explicitly allowed there.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Is there a possibility to easily move it over there including comments and current answers?

Comment: That has to be done by a moderator -- you can raise a flag asking one to do so.

Answer (score 1):

1. Avoid commits directly to main.
2. Always update branches with rebase.

   - This includes `git pull`. Configure [`pull.rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pullrebase) to `merges`.
3. Require branches be up to date before merging.
4. Put a summary of the branch and metadata (issue #, etc) about the branch in the merge commit.

"Update" merges have no historical value and only serve to complicate the history. Avoid them.

Requiring branches to be up-to-date before merging means what you test in the branch is what will be merged into main.

The result is "feature bubbles" like so.

```
A -------- M1 --------- M2 [main]
 \         /\         /
  1 - 2 - 3  4 - 5 - 6
```

The history is linear, yet preserves the grouping of commits into branches. You can look at just the merge commits with `git log --first-parent`.

Comment: I cannot disagree more strongly; if you don't have merge commits you don't know when things hit main, and when you force a rebase, you lose the ability to determine that something was developed correctly and corrupted during rebase or merge -- which can be important for accurate post mortem of how a bug came to be introduced.

Comment: Granted, this is a place where git is broadly inferior to its predecessors -- BitKeeper let you have it both ways, maintaining a visually clean timeline but still being able to drill down.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy There are merge commits with main, M1 and M2 above.

Answer (score 0):

The two most popular solutions to this problem afaik are:

- [rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) - not great for shared feature branches (i.e. multiple people working on the same branch)  as it modifies the source branch's history
- squashing upon merge - not great for long lived feature branches as the commit in the target branch is different to the the sources commits and reusing the source branch can get messy.

  - GitHub's [Squash and merge your commits](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/about-pull-request-merges#squash-and-merge-your-commits):

    > You can use squash and merge to create a more streamlined Git history in your repository.
  - Azure DevOps' [Merge strategies and squash merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging-with-squash?view=azure-devops):

    > Squash merging is a merge option that allows you to condense the Git history of topic branches when you complete a pull request. Instead of each commit on the topic branch being added to the history of the default branch, a squash merge adds all the file changes to a single new commit on the default branch. Squash merge commit doesn't have a reference to the topic branch, it will produce a new commit, that contains all changes from the topic branch. Furthermore it is recommended to delete the topic branch to prevent any confusion.